# Is centos 7 fixable if /var/cache is deleted?

Tags: centos

I created a CentOS 7 instance on AWS.  A friend deleted the `/var/cache` directory 'accidentally'.  I am no longer able to SSH into the box but the apache server running on the server is accessible via port 80.  Is it possible to 'fix' the instance so that I am able to SSH into the instance again?

Note:
I can create a new instance of the same type.  I can also detach the partition from 'broken' instance and attach it to new instance.

Comment: So what is the idea, to hack Apache's root process...?

Comment: Nothing sinister.  If the /var/cache is fixable, i can continue to use the same instance.  Otherwise, i have to create a new instance and recreate users, firewall rules, transfer files, etc.  Just trying to save time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can easily attach the volume as an additional drive to another system then just do that. Then you can simply copy the subtree.

```
cp -a /var/cache /mnt/damaged_root/var
```

Comment: I will give this a shot.  I'm no centos guru but wanted to see if an expert out there thinks that this will work before I try it.

Comment: @Ali That should work if the same software is installed on both systems. If not then there may be directories missing. You could have `rpm` check the files of all installed packages afterwards.

Comment: Attempted this but it did not work.  Maybe he deleted additional files.  Resorted back to creating a new instance of centos 7 and keeping the old filesystem as a mount.